# Unable to deploy Phoenix 1.3.0-rc1 to Heroku, builds but crashes

Tags: heroku, deployment, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to deploy a Phoenix 1.3.0-rc1 to Heroku.

It builds properly but I'm unable to access the website. It might be useful to notice that I'm able to access the app while running Phoenix on my machine.

Also worth noticing that I'm using SSL.

**This is  `$ heroku logs --tail` output:**

```
2017-03-31T01:45:15.876452+00:00 app[api]: Release v14 created by user me@jonathansoifer.com
2017-03-31T01:44:31.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2017-03-31T01:45:21.350931+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `MIX_ENV=prod mix phx.server`
2017-03-31T01:45:23.798042+00:00 app[web.1]:     exited: {{shutdown,
2017-03-31T01:45:23.798041+00:00 app[web.1]:     application: customer_acquisition
2017-03-31T01:45:23.798015+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-03-31T01:45:23.798040+00:00 app[web.1]: =INFO REPORT==== 31-Mar-2017::01:45:23 ===
2017-03-31T01:45:23.798042+00:00 app[web.1]:               {failed_to_start_child,
2017-03-31T01:45:23.798043+00:00 app[web.1]:                'Elixir.CustomerAcquisition.Web.Endpoint',
2017-03-31T01:45:23.798044+00:00 app[web.1]:                {shutdown,
2017-03-31T01:45:23.798051+00:00 app[web.1]:                 {failed_to_start_child,'Elixir.Phoenix.Endpoint.Handler',
2017-03-31T01:45:23.798052+00:00 app[web.1]:                  {shutdown,
2017-03-31T01:45:23.798053+00:00 app[web.1]:                    {ranch_listener_sup,
2017-03-31T01:45:23.798053+00:00 app[web.1]:                   {failed_to_start_child,
2017-03-31T01:45:23.798054+00:00 app[web.1]:                     'Elixir.CustomerAcquisition.Web.Endpoint.HTTP'},
2017-03-31T01:45:23.798054+00:00 app[web.1]:                    {'EXIT',
2017-03-31T01:45:23.798055+00:00 app[web.1]:                     {noproc,
2017-03-31T01:45:23.798056+00:00 app[web.1]:                      {gen_server,call,
2017-03-31T01:45:23.798057+00:00 app[web.1]:                        {set_new_listener_opts,
2017-03-31T01:45:23.798056+00:00 app[web.1]:                       [ranch_server,
2017-03-31T01:45:23.798058+00:00 app[web.1]:                         'Elixir.CustomerAcquisition.Web.Endpoint.HTTP',16384,
2017-03-31T01:45:23.798058+00:00 app[web.1]:                         [{env,
2017-03-31T01:45:23.798059+00:00 app[web.1]:                           [{dispatch,
2017-03-31T01:45:23.798060+00:00 app[web.1]:                             [{'_',[],
2017-03-31T01:45:23.798060+00:00 app[web.1]:                               [{[>,>],
2017-03-31T01:45:23.798061+00:00 app[web.1]:                                 [],'Elixir.Phoenix.Endpoint.CowboyWebSocket',
2017-03-31T01:45:23.798062+00:00 app[web.1]:                                 {'Elixir.Phoenix.Transports.WebSocket',
2017-03-31T01:45:23.798062+00:00 app[web.1]:                                  {'Elixir.CustomerAcquisition.Web.Endpoint',
2017-03-31T01:45:23.798063+00:00 app[web.1]:                                   'Elixir.CustomerAcquisition.Web.UserSocket',
2017-03-31T01:45:23.798063+00:00 app[web.1]:                                   websocket}}},
2017-03-31T01:45:23.798064+00:00 app[web.1]:                                {'_',[],'Elixir.Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler',
2017-03-31T01:45:23.798064+00:00 app[web.1]:                                 {'Elixir.CustomerAcquisition.Web.Endpoint',
2017-03-31T01:45:23.798065+00:00 app[web.1]:                                  []}}]}]}]}]}]}}}}}}}}},
2017-03-31T01:45:23.798066+00:00 app[web.1]:              {'Elixir.CustomerAcquisition.Application',start,[normal,[]]}}
2017-03-31T01:45:23.798066+00:00 app[web.1]:     type: permanent
2017-03-31T01:45:23.870799+00:00 app[web.1]: ** (exit) exited in: GenServer.call(Mix.State, {:get, {Map, :get, [:debug, false]}}, 5000)
2017-03-31T01:45:23.870801+00:00 app[web.1]:     ** (EXIT) no process
2017-03-31T01:45:23.870802+00:00 app[web.1]:     (elixir) lib/gen_server.ex:596: GenServer.call/3
2017-03-31T01:45:23.870803+00:00 app[web.1]:     (mix) lib/mix/cli.ex:65: Mix.CLI.run_task/2
2017-03-31T01:45:23.870804+00:00 app[web.1]:     (elixir) lib/code.ex:363: Code.require_file/2
2017-03-31T01:45:23.870804+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-03-31T01:45:23.870999+00:00 app[web.1]: {"init terminating in do_boot",{noproc,{gen_server,call,[elixir_config,{get_and_put,at_exit,[]}]}}}
2017-03-31T01:45:23.871019+00:00 app[web.1]: init terminating in do_boot ()
2017-03-31T01:45:23.871288+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-03-31T01:45:25.175329+00:00 app[web.1]: Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done
2017-03-31T01:45:25.225434+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-03-31T01:45:25.238818+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-03-31T01:45:33.319992+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=liberty.ai request_id=2de26102-043c-4635-aee0-df1c0f812fd1 fwd="191.183.100.215,172.68.25.249" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2017-03-31T01:45:33.968974+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=liberty.ai request_id=f3f5e957-5796-4354-ade2-69bd7bc60c84 fwd="191.183.100.215,172.68.27.167" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this same error, it turns out that phoenix 1.3.0-rc1 requires elixir 1.4. If you add an `elixir_buildpack.config`, you can set the elixir version like so:

```
elixir_version=1.4.2
```

I found this solution here: https://github.com/HashNuke/heroku-buildpack-elixir/issues/99.